# Pack method called from actionPerformed functions only sometimes

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

***Problem***

Upon compiling and running my program multiple times, sometimes `pack()` works and the components of `newGamePanel` are compressed, and sometimes it doesn't work, and `newGamePanel` expands to fill the `JFrame` values set by `setSize()`. I have been unable to reliably reproduce either result-- it really seems to be random.

Note: As I cut down on the amount of GUI formatting to have a reasonable amount of code to review, the GUI is pretty trash. However, the problem is still easy to identify. When the `JPanel` that's supposed to be packed is shown by `CardLayout`, sometimes the `JFrame` is the "packed" size and sometimes it matches the `setSize()` values I set in the beginning. Now that I cut the GUI, the `newGamePanel` components don't move to fill their container, but that's just because I removed all their constraint values.

**Suspicions and design**

I am calling `pack()` from class `TankEvent`, which implements `ActionListener`. Game is a `TankApplication` object (`TankApplication` extends `JFrame`) passed to `TankEvent` in the `TankEvent` constructor, which is called by `TankDisplay` (`TankDisplay` extends `JPanel`).

`JFrame` instantiates `JPanel`, passes instance of self.
`JPanel` instantiates `ActionListener`, passes instance of self.
`ActionListener` modifies `JFrame` using `pack()`.

The following is the code executed when a button is pressed.

```
CardLayout layOut = (CardLayout)(display.getLayout()); //display is an object of TankDisplay
layOut.show(display, "newGamePanel"); 
game.pack(); //game is an object of TankApplication
game.setResizable(false);
break;
```

I wonder if the issue is in my design. I'm making a huge assumption that `pack()` repaints the `JFrame` (are `JFrames` even repainted? Perhaps revalidates/updates?). But as long as I reset the size of `JFrame` when I'm done, I'm not sure why it would be an issue..

(Side question, I'm not sure why I need to cast `display.getLayout()` as a `CardLayout`. This is the suggested implementation from docs.oracle, but why does `getLayout()` return a LayoutManager and not the actual LayoutManager...?)

**Shortened Relevant Code**

Tank Display

```
package Tanks;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.*;

public class TankDisplay extends JPanel{
    JCheckBox unlimitedAmmoCB, unlimitedTimeCB;
    JTextField playerOneTF, playerTwoTF;
    JPanel menuPanel, newGamePanel;

    public TankDisplay(TankApplication g){
        TankEvent listener = new TankEvent(this, g); //passing an instance of self and previously received instance of TankApplication to TankEvent
        setLayout(new CardLayout()); //Hihghest level of GUI after JFrame. CardLayout for overall display JPanel, need for switching functionality in TankEvent

        menuPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout()); //Second highest level of GUI. Will eventually display a picture instead of a black JPanel. Has button "New Game" and "Load Game"

        JPanel mainMenuImageP = new JPanel();
        GridBagConstraints conMainMenuImageP = new GridBagConstraints();
        mainMenuImageP.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        conMainMenuImageP.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        conMainMenuImageP.gridy = 0;
        conMainMenuImageP.gridx = 0;
        menuPanel.add(mainMenuImageP, conMainMenuImageP); //adding menuPanel components

        JButton newGameB = new JButton("New Game");
        GridBagConstraints conNewGameB = new GridBagConstraints();
        conNewGameB.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        conNewGameB.gridy = 1;
        conNewGameB.gridx = 0;
        menuPanel.add(newGameB, conNewGameB); //adding menuPanel components

        JButton loadGameB = new JButton("Load Game");
        GridBagConstraints conLoadGameB = new GridBagConstraints();
        conLoadGameB.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        conLoadGameB.gridy = 1;
        conLoadGameB.gridx = 1;
        menuPanel.add(loadGameB, conLoadGameB); //adding menuPanel components

        //action listners for mainPenu panel components
        newGameB.addActionListener(listener);

        add(menuPanel, "menuPanel"); //menuPanel is added to higher display JPanel

        newGamePanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());                     //creating second higher level container. To achieve certain functionality, 
                                                                            //this panel contains four other panels, that each contain their own 
        JPanel playerOneSetUp = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());            //components. newGamePanel uses GridBagLayout, and so do the panels
            GridBagConstraints conPlayerOneSetUp = new GridBagConstraints();//that it's managing. GridBayLayout managaing GridBagLayout
            conPlayerOneSetUp.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            conPlayerOneSetUp.gridy = 0;
            conPlayerOneSetUp.gridx = 0;

        JLabel playerOneL = new JLabel("Player One Name");
            GridBagConstraints conPlayerOneL = new GridBagConstraints();
            conPlayerOneL.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            conPlayerOneL.gridy = 0;
            conPlayerOneL.gridx = 0;
            playerOneSetUp.add(playerOneL, conPlayerOneL);

        playerOneTF = new JTextField();
            GridBagConstraints conPlayerOneTF = new GridBagConstraints();
            conPlayerOneTF.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            conPlayerOneTF.gridy = 1;
            conPlayerOneTF.gridx = 0;
            playerOneSetUp.add(playerOneTF, conPlayerOneTF);

        JButton playerOneJColorChooser = new JButton("Player One Color");
            GridBagConstraints conPlayerOneJColorChooser = new GridBagConstraints();
            conPlayerOneJColorChooser.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            conPlayerOneJColorChooser.gridy = 2;
            conPlayerOneJColorChooser.gridx = 0;
            playerOneSetUp.add(playerOneJColorChooser, conPlayerOneJColorChooser);

        newGamePanel.add(playerOneSetUp, conPlayerOneSetUp); //adding newGamePanel components

        JPanel playerTwoSetUp = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout()); 
            GridBagConstraints conPlayerTwoSetUp = new GridBagConstraints();
            conPlayerTwoSetUp.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            conPlayerTwoSetUp.gridy = 1;
            conPlayerTwoSetUp.gridx = 0;

        JLabel playerTwoL = new JLabel("Player Two Name");
            GridBagConstraints conPlayerTwoL = new GridBagConstraints();
            conPlayerTwoL.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            conPlayerTwoL.gridy = 0;
            conPlayerTwoL.gridx = 0;
            playerTwoSetUp.add(playerTwoL, conPlayerTwoL);

        playerTwoTF = new JTextField();
            GridBagConstraints conPlayerTwoTF = new GridBagConstraints();
            conPlayerTwoTF.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            conPlayerTwoTF.gridy = 1;
            conPlayerTwoTF.gridx = 0;
            playerTwoSetUp.add(playerTwoTF, conPlayerTwoTF);

        JButton playerTwoJColorChooser = new JButton("Player Two Color");
            GridBagConstraints conPlayerTwoJColorChooser = new GridBagConstraints();
            conPlayerTwoJColorChooser.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            conPlayerTwoJColorChooser.gridy = 2;
            conPlayerTwoJColorChooser.gridx = 0;
            playerTwoSetUp.add(playerTwoJColorChooser, conPlayerTwoJColorChooser);  

        newGamePanel.add(playerTwoSetUp, conPlayerTwoSetUp); //adding newGamePanel components

        JPanel options = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints conOptions = new GridBagConstraints();
            conOptions.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            conOptions.gridy = 0;
            conOptions.gridx = 1;

        JLabel optionsL = new JLabel("Game Options");
            GridBagConstraints conOptionsL = new GridBagConstraints();
            conOptionsL.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            conOptionsL.gridy = 0;
            conOptionsL.gridx = 0;
            options.add(optionsL, conOptionsL);

        unlimitedAmmoCB = new JCheckBox("Unlimited Ammunition");
            GridBagConstraints conUnlimitedAmmoCB = new GridBagConstraints();
            conUnlimitedAmmoCB.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            conUnlimitedAmmoCB.gridy = 1;
            conUnlimitedAmmoCB.gridx = 0;
            options.add(unlimitedAmmoCB, conUnlimitedAmmoCB);

        unlimitedTimeCB = new JCheckBox("Unlimited Time");          
            GridBagConstraints conUnlimitedTimeCB = new GridBagConstraints();
            conUnlimitedTimeCB.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            conUnlimitedTimeCB.gridy = 2;
            conUnlimitedTimeCB.gridx = 0;
            options.add(unlimitedTimeCB, conUnlimitedTimeCB);

        newGamePanel.add(options, conOptions); //adding newGamePanel components

        JButton startGameB = new JButton("START");
            GridBagConstraints conStartGameB = new GridBagConstraints();
            conStartGameB.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            conStartGameB.gridy = 1;
            conStartGameB.gridx = 1;

        newGamePanel.add(startGameB, conStartGameB); //adding newGamePanel components

        add(newGamePanel, "newGamePanel"); //newGamePanel is added to higher level display JPanel

    }
}
```

Tank Application

```
package Tanks;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class TankApplication extends JFrame{  
    public static void main (String args[]){    
        TankApplication GUI = new TankApplication();             
    }

    public TankApplication(){
        super("Tanks");
        add(new TankDisplay(this));
        setSize(800, 600);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

Tank Event

```
package Tanks;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.JColorChooser;
public class TankEvent implements ActionListener{

    TankApplication game;
    TankDisplay display;

    public TankEvent(TankDisplay d, TankApplication g){ //I found this was necesarry because I didn't want to call the constructors of panels
        display = d;                                    //and frames. I'm not sure why that caused errors, but it does. And when I tried to
        game = g;                                       //create overloaded constructors for TankApplication and TankDisplay, their references
    }                                                   //didn't have the information I needed. This is likely because I kept most of the components
                                                        //as local variables in the constructors, instead of creating variables in their respective classes, and using 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){         //the constructors to modify them
        CardLayout layOut = (CardLayout)(display.getLayout()); //<---Why do I need to do this?
        switch(e.getActionCommand()){
            case "New Game":
                layOut.show(display, "newGamePanel");
                game.pack();    //<<<---Root problem. Sometimes newGamePanel is packed, the JFrame is smaller, sometimes newGameaPanel is not packed. Seems random
                game.setResizable(false); //for this JPanel only, I don't want to be able to resize the window. I will change this when the user flips
                break;                    //to another JPanel       
        }
    }
}
```

Robert seems to have asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325287/jdialog-fails-to-pack-only-sometimes), but didn't seem to get a satisfactory answer. Why do threads have anything to do with this?

Comment: *"Relevant code:"* Often code problems are actually in an entirely different part of the app. than where we expect. For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I read both of those articles, but let me verify. Basically, I need to cut everything excess out of my code that I don't need to reproduce the problem. Which will not only help me isolate the problem, but will give everyone a manageable amount of code to look at?

Comment: I made the edits. I'm pretty sure that's an MCV.

Comment: `I'm pretty sure that's an MCV` - actually its not. Your question is about packing a frame. The pack() method works by determining the preferred size of all the components. So the actual components on the panel are irrelevant. For the purpose of an MCVE you can just create a panel and hard code a preferred size of the panel. and then see if your logic works.

Comment: I had thought that if I didn't place components in the panel, I wouldn't be able to tell if they were being packed or not. I recognize I could probably have a single component, and `pack()` would recommend a small frame, so I could reproduce the problem that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `CardLayout` correctly.

When you use a `CardLayout` on a panel the preferred size of the panel is the size of the largest child panel added to the CardLayout.

Swapping from one panel to another will not alter the preferred size of panel and therefore the frame. So the pack() method will have no effect.

I suggest you don't worry about packing the frame. Just create the "menu panel" so that its components are centered. Then when you start the game all that changes is that you display the "game panel".

Comment: That is an excellent solution, but I'm not sure it answers the question of why pack() sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. I understand now why it wouldn't work, but it's not true that pack() doesn't have effect, because sometimes it does alter the size of the frame.

Comment: @ulw1, well like I said you didn't post a proper `MCVE` so I can't test your code to try to understand what you are doing.